# How can the default css affect rendered html object page

Tags: html, css

I got the page (can control the content) which can only run html (not javascript) like this:

```
<style>
h1 { color:red }
</style>
<object data=something.html ></object>
```

in something.html, it contains:

```
<h1>
simple example
</h1>
```

and the css not work in this case, I expect the `simple example` to be red, it still black. Is there possibly any way that my css affect the rendered html source? (can replace object tag with any tag)

Comment: Try adding `h1 { color: red !important;}`

Comment: Refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42063330/styling-object-tag-inner-content

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<style>
h1 { color:red }
</style>
```

in `something.html`

Hope it is the way you looking for .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
<style>
h1 { color:red !important }
</style>
<h1>
simple example
</h1>
```